# In RxJS, should complete be called in an observable that emits no items?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

In my [last post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62812024/rxjs-how-to-emit-values-of-a-certain-buffer-size-with-a-delay-between-each-grou), I was trying to buffer pending http requests using RxJS. I thought `bufferCount` was what I needed, but I found it my items were under the buffer size, it would just wait, which is not what I was after.

I now have a new scheme, using `take`. It seems to do what I am after, except when my resulting observable has no items (left), the complete is never called.

Eg I have something like the following..

```
      const pendingRequests = this.store$.select(mySelects.getPendingRequests).pipe(
      // FlatMap turns the observable of a single Requests[] to observable of Requests
      flatMap(x => x),

      // Only get requests unprocessed
      filter(x => x.processedState === ProcessedState.unprocessed),

      // Batches of batchSize in each emit
      take(3),
    );
    
    let requestsSent = false;
    pendingRequests.subscribe(nextRequest => {           
      requestsSent = true;
      this.sendRequest(nextEvent);           
     },
      error => {            
        this.logger.error(`${this.moduleName}.sendRequest:  Error ${error}`);
      },
      () => {         
        // ****  This is not called if pendingRequests is empty ****
        if (requestsSent ) {              
          this.store$.dispatch(myActions.continuePolling());              
        } else {
          this.store$.dispatch(myActions.stopPolling());              
        }
      }
    );
```

So the `take(3)` will get the next 3 pending requests and send them ()where I also dispatch an action to set the processed state to not ProcessedState.pending so we don't get them in the next poll)

This all works fine, but when `pendingRequests` eventually returns nothing (is empty), the `completed` block, marked with the ****. is not called. I would have thought this would just be called straight away.

I am not sure if this matters, as since I don't then dispatch the action to continue polling, the polling does stop.

But my biggest concern is if `pendingRequests` is not completed, do I need to unsubscribe from it to prevent any leaks? I assume if the `complete` **is** called I do not need to unsubscribe?

### Update

To get the `pendingReguests`to always complete, I have taken a slightly different approach. Rather than using the `rx` operators to "filter", I Just get the whole list every time, and just `take(1)` on it. I will always get the list, even if it is empty, so the `pendingReguests` will complete every time.

ie

```
const pendingRequests = this.store$.select(mySelects.getPendingRequests).pipe(take(1))
```

And then I can just filter  and batch inside the observable..

```
 pendingRequests.subscribe(nextRequest => {
      let requestToSend = nextRequest.filter(x => x.processedState === ProcessedState.unprocessed);
      const totalPendingCount = requestToSend.length;
      requestToSend = requestToSend slice(0, this.batchSize);          
      for (const nextRequest of requestToSend) {                  
          this.sendRequest(nextRequest);            
      }

      if (totalPendingCount > this.batchSize) {
        this.store$.dispatch(myActions.continuePolling());            
      }
```

In my testing so far, I have now always got the `complete` to fire.

Also, by having 2 actions (a startPolling, and a continuePolling) I can put the delay just in the continuePolling, so the first time we start the polling (eg the app has just come back online after being out of network range), we submit straight away, and only delay if we have more than the batch size

Maybe this is not 100% the "rxy" way of doing it, but seems to work so far. Is there any problem here?

Comment: What does "pendingRequests eventually returns nothing (is empty)" exactly mean? Does it emit a value (like undefined/null) or is there just never coming any response. If never any response is being returned, you need to decide how long you want to wait. With this information we can make a running "wait until" and after the given time complete the observable.

Answer (score 0):

I would substitute `take` with `toArray` and a bit of buffering logic afterwards.

This is how your code could look like. I have added the `delay` logic, which I think was suggested by your previous post, and provided comments to describe each line added

```
// implementation of the chunk function used below
// https://www.w3resource.com/javascript-exercises/fundamental/javascript-fundamental-exercise-265.php
   const chunk = (arr, size) =>
      Array.from({ length: Math.ceil(arr.length / size) }, (v, i) =>
        arr.slice(i * size, i * size + size)
      );

  const pendingRequests = this.store$.select(mySelects.getPendingRequests).pipe(
  // FlatMap turns the observable of a single Requests[] to observable of Requests
  flatMap(x => x),

  // Only get requests unprocessed
  filter(x => x.processedState === ProcessedState.unprocessed),

  // Read all the requests and store them in an array
  toArray(),
  // Split the array in chunks of the specified size, in this case 3
  map(arr => chunk(arr, 3)), // the implementation of chunk is provided above
  // Create a stream of chunks
  concatMap((chunks) => from(chunks)),
  // make sure each chunk is emitted after a certain delay, e.g. 2 sec
  concatMap((chunk) => of(chunk).pipe(delay(2000))),
  // mergeMap to turn an array into a stream
  mergeMap((val) => val)
);

let requestsSent = false;
pendingRequests.subscribe(nextRequest => {           
  requestsSent = true;
  this.sendRequest(nextEvent);           
 },
  error => {            
    this.logger.error(`${this.moduleName}.sendRequest:  Error ${error}`);
  },
  () => {         
    // ****  THIS NOW SHOULD BE CALLED ****
    if (requestsSent ) {              
      this.store$.dispatch(myActions.continuePolling());              
    } else {
      this.store$.dispatch(myActions.stopPolling());              
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: Would it ever complete?

Comment: it completes because `toArray` completes and, after that, we just transform the array into chunks which have a clearly defined length and therefore complete

Comment: According to the  documentations `toArray` collects all source emissions and emits them as an array when the source completes. I can't see how the source will complete here

Comment: @Picci - thanks for that. I tried the above, but the line `pendingEvents.subscribe` never seemed to emit anything. I had a breakpoint inside it, but it was never hit.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that `pendingRequests` will ever complete by itself. The `Store`, at least in ngrx, is a `BehaviorSubject`. So, whenever you do `store.select()` or `store.pipe(select())`, you're just adding another subscriber to the internal list of subscribers maintained by the `BehaviorSubject`.

The `BehaviorSubject` [extends `Subject`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/BehaviorSubject.ts#L13), and here is what happens when the `Subject` [is being subscribed to](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/Subject.ts#L133):

```js
this.observers.push(subscriber);
```

In your case, you're using `take(3)`. After 3 values, the `take` will emit a complete notification, so your `complete` callback should be called. And because the entire chain is actually a `BehaviorSubject`'s subscriber, it will remove itself from the subscribers list on `complete` notifications.

> I assume if the complete is called I do not need to unsubscribe

Here is what happens when a subscriber(e.g [`TakeSubscriber`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/operators/take.ts#L86)) [completes](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/Subscriber.ts#L147-L150):

```js
  protected _complete(): void {
    this.destination.complete();
    this.unsubscribe();
  }
```

So, there is no need to unsubscribe if a `complete`/`error` notification already occurred.

Comment: thanks for that explanation. So once I take the 3, I want to "poll" again, using the myActions.continuePolling(). I have an effect for the continuePolling action, which has a delay (using `rxjs delay`), and then call above method again. I do this to first get any more that were already in the pending list, and also in-case there have been any new added . This will keep going until there are none left, so there will be one more call when the list is empty. This is where the `complete` is not called. In this case do I need to/how do I unsubscribe from the pendingEvents.subscribe?

Comment: Damn I have realised the subscription does not complete unless `take` gets it's full count.  Ie if I just just one pending request, and I use take(2), pendingRequests will not complete. I tried piping into a `timeout` but did not seem to help.

Comment: So what you want to achieve is if take’s count is not reached within ‘n milliseconds’, you’d like to complete, right?

Comment: What should happen with the timer if take’s count is reached and continuePolling is dispatched?

Comment: I have changed my direction her a little. I've out and update ([UPDATE Jul 14 20]) in the original post. Basically I am just going to grab the whole list as a single Take(1), since I know I will always get exactly one element (ie the list, even if it is empty). I think this makes it all a lot simpler, and I can't see their should be any problems with it, since I now always get the complete called (I hope :-0)