# Angular, Split an Array into Batches and make HTTP server calls, Wait on Previous call before making the next

Tags: angular, rxjs

New With Angular Please help

I have an Array of Numbers, I'm looking to Split the array into chunks and make server post call. I Only want to make the next request after the previous request is complete and hasn't failed

Note if I receive an error response I need to stop making any further calls
When making the server post call I'm sending through the entire list

I was thinking of doing something like this

```
 const chunkSize = 10;

    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i += chunkSize) {
         const chunk = array.slice(i, i + chunkSize);
         dataservice.postData(chunk)          // Make http call
         // Not sure how to wait for the call before continuing with the loop
     }
```

I'm sure their is smarter way of doing this using RXJS.

For Context this is the flow.

Component -> data-service -> api service (a service that handles all http requests)-> Server

Data service

```
  postData(Ids: number[])
    : Observable<WebApiResponse<boolean>> {
      return this.ApiService.post(route, endpoint, Ids);
    }
```

api service -> makes the request to the server.

Server is a void method

EDIT: This is what I ended up going with

```
const ids$ = from(this.Ids);//Obeservable of my list of ID's
this.subscription = ids$.pipe(
  takeWhile(() => this.isExecuting),
  bufferCount(this.batchSize),
  concatMap((batch) => {
    return this.DataService.validate(<object>{ Ids: batch }).pipe(
      takeWhile((result) => {
        return result.Status === WebApiResponseStatus.Success && this.isExecuting;
      }),
      tap(() => {
        this.completed += batch.length;
        this.completedPercentage = this.completed / this.totalCount * 100;
        if (this.completed >= this.totalCount) {
          this.isExecuting = false;
        }
      })
    );
  })
).subscribe({
  error: () => {
    this.isExecuting = false;
    this.error = true;
  }
});
```

Comment: `concat` operator will do that for you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rxjs: Chunk and delay stream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41403500/rxjs-chunk-and-delay-stream)

Answer (score 0):

`concat` will do the trick. I am assuming that `this.ApiService.post` returns cold observable

```
    const batches=[];
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i += chunkSize) {
         const chunk = array.slice(i, i + chunkSize);
         batches.push(dataservice.postData(chunk).pipe(
            switchMap(result=> result ? of(true):throw(`Batch ${i} failed`)));
         )
     }

   concat(batches).pipe(toArray()).subscribe(()=>console.log("all done"));
```

or even better:

```
of(...array).pipe(
   bufferCount(chunkSize),
   map((chunk)=>dataservice.postData(chunk).pipe(
                switchMap(result=> result ? of(true):throw(`Batch failed`))),
  concatAll(),
  toArray(),
).subscribe(results=>console.log("all done",results);
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-yze6rx?file=index.ts

Answer (score 0):

OPTION 1

In yor service.ts:

```
  save(yourJson): Observable<YourModel> {
    
    const URL = 'http://your.end.pont.com';

    return this.http.post<YourModel>(`URL`, {yourJson}).pipe(
      tap((responseOne) => {
        
        // here you can set your new chained request
        save(responseOne): Observable<OtherModel> { ...more code}

      }),
      catchError(err => throwError(err))
    );
  }
```

OPTION 2 (using subcription in controller with pipe())

You also can chained request into pipe() in your controller. May you want use tap(), or in finalize() nested subcripcion() of the service invoke in your controller.

Is bad practice to chained request... may you need review your logic...
You only need One request, backend must to deliver one result.